# C Initialize array to pointers from inside function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array, initialization

I need to understand how to initialize an array of pointers from inside the function in C, why I must initialize the array with `(*object_array)` not just `object_array`, `**object_array` or `***object_array` what are `***pointer` exactly mean? I do understand single pointer and its math but double+ pointers are really confusing me.

```
size_t array_size = 5;
Object **object_array;

function_init_array(&object_array, array_size);

void function_init_array(Object ***object_array, size_t array_size) {
    (*object_array) = mnabil_memory_allocate(array_size * sizeof(Object*));
}
```

Comment: Perhaps forget about double pointers for a moment and try to write a function that initialises an `int`. You have an `int` variable and you need to pass it to a function `init_my_int` which initialises it to 42. How would `init_my_int` look like?

Comment: In a declaration, when you see `*` you say "pointer to a".  So `***object_array` means "pointer to a pointer to a pointer to object_array".  You don't see `***` very often and it can be an indication of poor design.  In your code it would be simpler if your function returned the allocated pointer instead of modifying its argument.

Comment: Please give more background/context. At least make the code quote compilable, if not an [mcve] of the situation in which you want to init.